# extjs 6 admin-dashboard source code

Tags: forms, extjs, extjs6

I am looking at the extjs6 examples... admin-dashboard.
Then on the left panel... FORMS.
How can I see the source code for this specific form in that example?
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You should download ExtJS framework first. After unpack, you can find source files of the form screen in `templates/admin-dashboard/modern/src/view/forms` folder.